# NA in alphanumerical data

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a variable Account_No. in which is in number format. I have account numbers that are numeric (2607242, 2607141) and alphanumeric (NWU14, NWU32). I see that all the alphanumeric data are NA. Please suggest how can I make those account number that are in alphanumeric format appear in my data set?

I tried:
as.numeric(x$Account_No."

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds like you started off with either a character or factor vector/column, then tried to coerce it to numeric, e.g.

```
x <- c("2607242", "2607141", "NWU14", "NWU32")
as.numeric(x)

[1] 2607242 2607141      NA      NA
```

This also generates the warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

If you intend to store values like `NWU14`, which contain characters other than numbers, then you should leave the type as character or factor.